# copy file (using bash) as new file and edit variables within the file

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a `python` file (`.py`) which I am trying to copy via bash, which is quite strightforward like so:

```
cp filename.py filename1.py
```

However, what I want to do is change a few variables when this copy happens. So, the contents of the filename.py are like so:

```
....
DEBUG = True
def new()
    var=3
    return False
other contents..
```

when the copy happens, I want `filename1.py to have:

```
....
DEBUG = True
def new()
    var=4
    return False
other contents..
```

How can achieve this in one line using bash? So, in the new file, the want the variables `DEBUG` and `var` to have different values.

I am assuming it will be a combination of `grep` and `cat` but I am not able to think how to use these to achieve the desired result.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

`cat infile.py | sed 's/\DEBUG\ \=\ True/DEBUG\ \=\ False/g' > outfile.py`

Comment: does not work. I tried `cat in.py | sed 's/Debug = True/Debug = False/g' >out.py` but nothing has changed in out.py

Comment: Please check the modified answer. You need to check case and escape symbols.

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks. so, if I want to change another variable in the same file, can i chain the commands?

Comment: You can chain commands with a pipe, or `sed` supports multiple commands using `-e` with this syntax: `sed -e 's/something/blah/g' -e 's/somethingelse/foo/g'`